# php mysql, Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in info.php on line 59

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to perform a mysql insert operation but for some reasons I get the ugly error:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in info.php on line 59

the code is:

```
<?php
 $db_usag_down = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","user","XXXXXXXX","down");
  $db_usag_full = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","user","XXXXXXXXXX","full");

$insert_query = $db_usag_down->prepare("INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insert_query->bind_param('issssi', $account_id, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $country, $full_status);


$insert_query->execute();
 if ($insert_query->errno) {
  echo "FAILURE!!! " . $insert_query->error();
?>
```

Sample values:

> 23232, Michael K, Boli Gnawaboli@example.com, Cote D'Ivoire (ivory Coast), 1

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see:

- First, and actual error, your [`INSERT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is incorrect. It needs to include a column list and/or `VALUES` before `(?, ?, ...)`.
- Second, your parameter count for `bind_param()` is incorrect based on your query.

Comment: I edit the question and added the VALUES parameter but I'm getting the same fatal error . Can you elaborate how the parameter count is incorrect ? I have six values to add so I added six '?'

Comment: You should probably specify the column list too as my guess is there are more columns in the Applicant table.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqli statement object was not correctly created, because the `INSERT` statement is invalid.  You're missing the `VALUES` keyword:

```
$insert_query = $db_usag_down->prepare("INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//
Check the error status of your `mysqli` object with `mysqli->error();`
if (!$insert_query) {
  echo $db_usag_down->error();
}
```

You will have other problems too.  You have more data types listed in your `bind_param` than you have variables to bind.

```
// You have six params, so you should have only six characters in the data types:
// Assumes $full_status is an integer
$insert_query->bind_param('issssi', $account_id, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $country, $full_status);
```